# UVA 3n+1 (prob 100) wrong answer but all the test cases are passed

Tags: c++

I've seen some questions about [3n+1 problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36) on stackoverflow and etc and tried to fix the mentioned tips to get the code correct. for example now I check if `a > b` or not. or i use `long long` instead of simple `int`. but still get wrong answer. what is wrong with my answer?

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int count_steps(long long int num)
{
    int counter = 1;
    while(num != 1)
    {
        if (num % 2 == 1)
            num = 3*num + 1;
        else
            num /= 2;

        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}

int max_between(long long int a , long long int b)
{
    int max=0,step;
    for(long long int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        if ((step = count_steps(i)) > max)
            max = step;
    }
    return max;
}

int main()
{
    int max=0,a,b,step;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    if (a >= b)
        cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << max_between(b,a) << endl;
    else
        cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << max_between(a,b) << endl;
    return 0;   
}
```

test cases:

```
1 10 (input)
1 10 20 (output)
900 1000 (input)
900 1000 174 (output)
1 1000000 (input)
1 1000000 525 (output)
1000000 1 (input)
1000000 1 525 (output)
```

Comment: The input may consist of multiple pairs. You are just reading one pair. The problem says 'a series of pairs' of integers shall be given to you but it does not specify from start, the number of pairs.

Comment: @Pooya Abhishek is right: "The input will consist of a series of pairs of integers". That's your only problem. The website also guarantees no overflow if a 32bit integer types is used, so you don't even need long long int.

Comment: Yeah you are right. tnx @AbhishekBansal and stefan !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some remarks to your code:

You're reading `a` and `b` as `int`, though using them as `long long int` in the methods. That's nonsense, read them as the type they are going to be used.

Although unlikely, you might experience overflows. To avoid that, you can double your range of integers by using `unsigned long long`.

Mathematically speaking, you're doing too much.

For an odd integer `n = 2 k + 1`, the result `3 n + 1` will always be even: `3 n + 1 = 3(2 k + 1) + 1 = 6k + 4`. Therefore you can combine the case for odd `n` with the following division by two. The result of that would be `3 k + 2` which is `k + 1` greater than `n`. Using integer arithmetic in C++, this is can be calculated with `n += (n / 2) + 1` as `n / 2` will evaluate to `k`.

Another possibility of why your code doesn't get accepted is input/output. You'll have to follow the exact requirements of the platform.

---

The following bit of the problem description is ignored by your code:

> The input will consist of a series of pairs of integers

This can be fixed easily

```
int main()
{
    int max=0,a,b,step;
    while ( cin >> a >> b )
    {
       std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ';
       if (a >= b)
       {
           std::cout << max_between(b,a);
       }
       else
       {
           std::cout << max_between(a,b);
       }
       std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```